# Run threads concurrently/simultaneously

Tags: python, json, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool

I am trying to run x amount threads simultaneously. I have a JSON file that has a list of profiles. Currently my code opens a thread for each profile (profile_0, profile_1..etc). I have simplified my while loop from my actual code but the premises is to grab the the Last_name of each profile in the thread.

The issue I am facing is the while loop runs each thread one after the other and not simultaneously. How would I go about an implementation where the while loop is run for all threads/profiles at the same time with minimal delay?

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import threading
from time import sleep
import random

with open('profileMulti.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
  config = json.loads(json_data, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)


def stringify(key, next_layer):
  sleep(random.random()) # work emulation
 
  # this print statement just for illustartion
  print(threading.current_thread().name, key)
  return { key: next_layer }  # still ordered

# how much workers should be started
profiles_number = len(config.get('Profiles', {}).items())

pool = ThreadPool(profiles_number)

# Launch a thread for each item and get() the results as each finishes
# `starmap_async` returns result object when all tasks are finished, so
# single get is called. Result object in thios case behave like list
results = pool.starmap_async(stringify, config.get('Profiles', {}).items()).get()

print('threaded results:')
for i in results:
    timeout = time.time()
    while True:
       print(str(config["Profiles"][str(next(iter(i)))][Last_name])
       if time.time() - timeout > 60:
          break
```

Json file:

```
      {
    "Profiles": {
        "profile_0": {
            "Url": "Myownwebsite.se",
            "My-Note": "Helloworld",
            "Email": "Stackoverflow@gmail.com"
            "PersonNumber": "1234543",
            "postal_code": "54123",
            "given_name": "World",
            "Last_name": "Hellow",
            "street_address": "helloworld 123",
            "city": "Stockholm",
            "country": "Sweden",
            "phone": "123456789",
            "Color": "Red",
            "house_number": "123",
            "year": "2017"
        },
        "profile_1": {
            "Url": "Myasdwfaesite.se",
            "My-Note": "aasfase",
            "Email": "fasfsef@gmail.com"
            "PersonNumber": "5634543",
            "postal_code": "123445",
            "given_name": "Balling",
            "Last_name": "Calling",
            "street_address": "qwertr 123",
            "city": "London",
            "country": "UK",
            "phone": "65412331",
            "Color": "Blue",
            "house_number": "321",
            "year": "2018"
        }
```

**EDITIED:**

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from multiprocessing import Pool
import threading
from time import sleep
import random

def main():

with open('profileMulti.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
  config = json.loads(json_data, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)


def stringify(key, next_layer):
  sleep(random.random()) # work emulation
 
  # this print statement just for illustartion
  print(threading.current_thread().name, key)
  return { key: next_layer }  # still ordered

# how much workers should be started
profiles_number = len(config.get('Profiles', {}).items())

pool = Pool(profiles_number)

# Launch a thread for each item and get() the results as each finishes
# `starmap_async` returns result object when all tasks are finished, so
# single get is called. Result object in thios case behave like list
results = pool.starmap_async(stringify, config.get('Profiles', {}).items()).get()

print('threaded results:')
for i in results:
    timeout = time.time()
    while True:
       print(str(config["Profiles"][str(next(iter(i)))][Last_name])
       if time.time() - timeout > 60:
          break

if __name__=='__main__'
   main()
```

Comment: Assuming you're dealing with CPython, you'd need to look into multiprocessing (pool) and not miltithreading: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock in order to allow actual parallel execution of concurrent code.

Comment: @OndrejK. yup I am aware of that hence why I am using ThreadPool from multiprocessing.pool.

Comment: Python's "global interpreter lock" means that only one thread gets to be running Python code at any time.  If you have code that waits for I/O, threading does great.  If your code is CPU bound, then Python multithreading is not useful.  And `multiprocessing.ThreadPool` is still just threading.

Comment: @TimRoberts, if I'm understanding correctly I am 'mulit' threading in a single python process but due to the lock it is going to run one at a time. So what I really need to do is run each thread in a different python process?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: In short: use multiprocessing ([pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)). At a cost and with some limitations, both because you are looking at separate processes (address space) which need to communicate (and how the IPC is implemented for python multiprocessing). But if it needs to be able to run in parallel, in case of CPython, it needs to be a separate process.

Comment: Ok I am trying to implement "from multiprocessing import Pool". I am not sure what I would now change the current pool=ThreadPool(profiles_number) to?

Comment: You'd change it to from `ThreadPool` to `Pool` on that line... but a side note: you'd **usually** size your pool (executors / processes) on available resources, not on tasks to be performed).

Comment: Ah when I do that I get an error stating RuntimeError: An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

Comment: The json can be configured to have x amount of profiles and therefore x amount of threads in the pool. So you are saying I should cap  number of profiles the user can add to the json based on available resources?

Comment: @OndrejK I put my for loop in a function called profilename() and then called it in f __name__=="__main__": clause to try and solve the error but that too did not fix it.

Comment: @turtlecoder -- ALL of your one-time code needs to be in the `if __name__` clause.  Remember, with multiprocessing, each new process starts a NEW interpreter that runs your main script all over again from the beginning, but with `__name__` set to another value.  The code to read the JSON file and the code to create the pool must all be in the guarded section.

Comment: On the  cap... Normally, at some point there is no benefit (but cost) to spawn (and try to schedule)  too many processes at once. There isn't one size fits all, it depends on what the processes do, what resources could be the bottle neck (or even run out), and how they need to interact. Perhaps a number of CPUs (times some factor) could be a good starting point for "normal" use cases? But there are situations where available RAM can be a greater concern. Or I/O bandwidth. Input can be config, but... point being, pool size would commonly be derived from resources, not work itself).

Comment: @TimRoberts Ah you're right, I am opening a new process for each thread that needs the entire script so everything needs to be guarded in if__name__ clause. I have posted the edited function. I get a new error now AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'main.<locals>.stringify' seems to be an error associated with multiprocessing from my search so looking for a fix now. Will provide an update once I do

Comment: Error is with the def stringify function. The placement of the function needs to be modified.

Comment: I moved the stringify function into a seperate script and called stringify1.py. I then imported it to my main script using from stringify import *. My code runs now but the threads are still not running in parallel. The second profile name is only printed after the first profile loop is done.